# Median unbiasedness problem in Lehman & Romano

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, random-variables

I found the following question in the book $\textit{Testing Statistical Hypotheses}$ by Lehman & Romano, and although I sense it should be reasonably straight-forward (although I could be wrong), I'm at loss as to how to begin.

> A real number $m$ is a median for the random variable $Y$ if $\text{P}(Y\geq m)\geq \frac12$ and $\text{P}(Y\leq m)\geq \frac12$. Then all real $a_1,a_2$ such that $m\leq a_1\leq a_2$ or $m\geq a_1\geq a_2$ satisfy $\mathbb{E}|Y-a_1|\leq\mathbb{E}|Y-a_2|$.

I would like to show that the inequality above is true. Any help or references to some relevant posts on here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a visual approach:

Consider the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, perhaps something like

[image]

Now split the CDF $F(y)$ at a point $a$ and turn the upper part upside down using $1-F(y)$; in this illustration $a \lt m$ so there is a jump up in the resulting curve at $a$ because $F(a) \le \frac12 \le 1-F(a)$ (if instead $a \gt m$ there would have been a jump down)

[image]

and the shaded pink area area is $\mathbb E|Y-a| =\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}F(y)\,dy + \int\limits_{a}^{\infty}(1-F(y))\,dy $.

Now consider doing it twice at $a_2 \lt a_1 \lt m$ and superimposing. You can see from the extra orange area that $\mathbb E|Y-a_1| \le E|Y-a_2|$ and that the difference between them is $\int\limits_{a_2}^{a_1}(1-2F(y))\,dy \ge 0$ since $F(y) \le \frac12$ on this interval:

[image]

A similar argument would show that the area and $\mathbb E|Y-a|$ are minimised when the split and folding-over happens at the median $a=m$, since that is where $F(y)$ and $1 - F(y)$ cross each other